# How to split a column into multiple columns?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have all data in one column named 
`2010-10-18;18;11;0004;1;1` in csv file.

I want to separate it by `;` and create new columns named `date`,`time`,`nr1.nr2` in pandas-python. How can i do that?

Comment: When loading your data, use `read_csv(..., sep=';')`

Comment: Thats probably fastest closing of a question

Comment: Obvious dupe is obvious

Comment: it does not work. Do u even look at screenshots? i tried to use sep=';' and there was nothing diffrent